# Java - instantiating a class in a loop

Tags: java

I'm having an issue instantiating a class in Java, essentially it generates a new world every tick, which is a bit frustrating when the program runs.
Whereas all I need to do is instantiate it then access a variable inside the class.

Here's the code:

Background.java

```
public class Background extends UserView {
    private BufferedImage bg;    

    private static Game game;    

    public Background(World w, int width, int height) {        
        super(w, width, height);
        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(new File("data/background.jpg")); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBackground(Graphics2D g) {        
        super.paintBackground(g);  
        game = new Game();
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);   
        int level = game.getLevel();
        g.drawString("Level: " + level, 25, 25);
    }

}
```

Game.java

```
public Game() {
    // make the world
    level = 1;
    world = new Level1();
    world.populate(this);

    // make a view
    view = new Background(world, 500, 500);     

    // uncomment this to draw a 1-metre grid over the view
    // view.setGridResolution(1);

    // display the view in a frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Save the Princess");

    // quit the application when the game window is closed
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    // display the world in the window
    frame.add(view);
    // don't let the game window be resized
    frame.setResizable(false);
    // size the game window to fit the world view
    frame.pack();
    // make the window visible
    frame.setVisible(true);
    // get keyboard focus
    frame.requestFocus();
    // give keyboard focus to the frame whenever the mouse enters the view
    view.addMouseListener(new GiveFocus(frame));

    controller = new Controller(world.getPlayer());
    frame.addKeyListener(controller);

    // start!
    world.start();
}

   /** Run the game. */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it for some reason just loops round and round when I run the game, have updated with the code from the main class.

Answer (score 0):

Well you probably need to think about the class concept nad its dependencies, but this is the easiest and fastest approach in your case to keep only one instance of Game :

```
public class Background extends UserView {

    private BufferedImage bg;

    private static Game game = new Game();

    public Background(World w, int width, int height) {
        super(w, width, height);
        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(new File("data/background.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBackground(Graphics2D g) {
        super.paintBackground(g);
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
        int level = game.getLevel();
        g.drawString("Level: " + level, 25, 25);
    }
}
```

If you add more code and say what you want and what you get, we can say you more about it.

Comment: Thank you, i've added more code as to where the issue is occuring.

Comment: It is still not enough to say you what to do better :).

Comment: Essentially I need to instantiate Game in the background class but it keeps generating a new game each time I choose run, on a loop.

Comment: What about World, what about UserView... there are more classes, it looks like you are not using them right.